# How do I open a grib dataset in grads in Windows?

Tags: gis, weather, grib, grads

I've tried all methods but I've faced a block at some point in time. I'm an amateur weather-data "collector" so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read grib files, you need to make a control (ctl) file for that grib file using wgrib2. Then make index files (idx) for that ctl. Then you will be able to read the control file of your data.

Follow the instructions from here.
https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/g2ctl.html

```
g2ctl -O grib2_file >grib2_file.ctl
gribmap -O -i grib2_file.ctl
grads
Landscape mode? (no for portrait):
ga-> open grib2_file.ctl
```

Or you can watch a simple video on how to do it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb8vhdMtTRs